# StoryQ BDD calling a Task C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd, storyq

I have a test where I want to use a function which returns a **Task**

Function

```
 public async Task FuncExceuted()
```

My test

```
 [Test]
    public void CreateNewProject()
    {
        _story.WithScenario("Create a new  Project for Bayer sensor")
            .Given(InitParameters())
            .When(await FuncExceuted())
            .Then(AssertFunction())
            .Execute();
    }
```

is there a way to use StoryQ because these are the errors I get:
 *error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'StoryQ.Scenario.Given(System.Action)' has some invalid arguments*
*error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'*

**Update:**
I also tried

```
[Test]

public async void CreateNewProject()
{
    _story.WithScenario("Create a new  Project for Bayer sensor")
        .Given(InitParameters)
        .When(await FuncExceuted)
        .Then(AssertFunction)
        .Execute();
}
```

*error CS4001: Cannot await 'method group'*
 *error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'StoryQ.Condition.When(System.Action)' has some invalid arguments*
*error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action'*

**Update 2:**

[Test]

```
public async Task CreateNewProject()
{
    _story.WithScenario("Create a new  Project for Bayer sensor")
        .Given(InitParameters)
        .When(async ()=> await FuncExceuted())
        .Then(AssertFunction)
        .Execute();
}
```

it is compiling! but runtime error 
ArgumentException -> *if you use 2 underscores in your method name, make sure there's 2 arguments (found 0)*

Comment: This has nothing to do with *tasks*. `Given` expects an Action delegate/lambda, not the result of *calling* the delegate

Comment: Now there are *two* bugs - `async void` is only meant for *event handlers*. The signature should be `async Task`. `await FuncExecuted` by itself should probably raise an error. It's the *lambda* that should be asynchronous. `await` operates on results though. It should be `async () => await FuncExecuted()`

Comment: hmmm let me try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error complains about `Given()`, not any tasks :

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'StoryQ.Scenario.**Given**(System.Action)' has some invalid arguments
>
> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from **'void'** to **'System.Action'**

Change :

```
.Given(InitParameters())
```

To :

```
.Given(InitParameters)
```

Or

```
.Given(() => InitParameters())
```

`Given()` expects an *Action* delegate, or something that can be converted to an Action. When the time comes to execute the test, *StoryQ* itself will call that action.

What you typed instead, calls the method immediatelly and passes the result (`void`) to `Given()`. That's why the compiler complains that it can't convert `void` to `Action`

**EDIT**

It looks like all calls have the same issues. All pass the *results* of a function call instead of the expected Action or Func.

The code should be replaced with :

```
   _story.WithScenario("Create a new  Project for Bayer sensor")
        .Given(()=>InitParameters())
        .When(async ()=>await FuncExceuted())
        .Then(() => AssertFunction())
        .Execute();
```

`FuncExecuted` isn't a *function*. It's an asynchronous method. Using the standard naming conventions for asynchronous methods, it should be named `ExecutedAsync`.

If StoryQ could deal with asynchronous methods, one could simply write :

```
        .When(()=>ExceutedAsync())
```

as well. It's not `async/await` that makes a method asynchronous, it's what goes on inside it and the return type of Task.

If StoryQ can't handle asynchronous methods, the method may have to be awaited explicitly, eg:

```
        .When(()=>FuncExceuted().Wait())
```

Comment: I tried this, it will give the same error The best overloaded method match for 'StoryQ.Scenario.When(System.Action)' has some invalid arguments, but for When....

Comment: @Gilad then do the same with `When`. The errors are not the same, but they *are* pretty clear

Comment: @Gilad which can't be answered by the code you typed here. This refers to your actual BDD description now. You should probably post a *new* question with the relevant code. There's no method with underscores in the code you posted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888815/storyq-when-calling-task-c-sharp  I posted a new question like you proposed